# SwiftUI not Releasing Memory for Deleted Cells in List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

If you create a list of the following view as rows:

```swift
struct ImageCellView: View {
    let image: UIImage

    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.image = image
    }

    var body: some View {
        return Image(uiImage: image).frame(height: 128).clipped()
    }
}
```

After cells are deleted, memory for UIImage is not released until new cells are added. Looking at the memory graph we can figure out that AGGraphStorage is holding reference for this:

[image]

Even if adding new cells can somehow free memory, UIImage is leaked occasionally:

[image]

Is this a bug in SwiftUI? Is there any way to get rid of this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a bug in SwiftUI?

No, it is not. `List` caches rows for reuse & performance purpose.

> Is there any way to get rid of this behavior?

Yes,

a) don't keep `UIImage` in member

b) manage `UIImage` in some other place and in struct keep it as `weak var image: UIImage?`

c) handle this in row's `.onDisappear`

d) ignore this, because List caches no more rows than fit on screen, so it will be reset when this row is used for other image

My preferable are a) and d), depending on use-case.

Comment: Both a) and b) do not work because references are apparently kept by SwiftUI internally. c) also does not work. For some reason onDisappear is not called after deleting rows. d) still does not work. Apparently List is caching all rows because if you add 100 rows, the memory usage will not go down until new rows are added even if you delete all rows.

Comment: I tried to emit event through NotificationCenter after a row is deleted and receive notification using onReceive in cell view. Then Image() is then replaced by Spacer(). It works. However memory is still not released. UIImage is still held by AGGraphStorage.

Comment: Even if it is cached, it should be removed after we pop that screen, right? But it doesn't.